# How to convert MD5 digest to int value (in python) that matches value generated in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, python-2.7, t-sql, md5

My goal is to generate a MD5 digest and convert it to an INT. I want to do this both in python and in SQL server and get back a matching value.

In SQL Server I generate an INT value using query below:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', 'ABCDEF') MD5Digest, CAST(HASHBYTES('MD5', 'ABCDEF') AS INTEGER) MD5DigestInt
--Query output:
-- MD5Digest,    MD5DigestInt 
-- 0x8827A41122A5028B9808C7BF84B9FCF6,   -2068185866
```

I can obtain the same value in C#:

```
var chars = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ABCDEF");
var bytes = h.ComputeHash(chars);
var hashId = BitConverter.ToInt32(h.ComputeHash(chars), 12);
hashId.Dump();
//Output: -151209596

hashId = System.Net.IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(hashId);
hashId.Dump();
//Output: -2068185866
```

So far in python 2.7 I've gotten close but not gotten the exact value yet:

```
import hashlib
import socket
import struct

chars = 'ABCDEF'.encode('utf-8')

m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(chars)
digest = bytearray(m.digest())
number = digest[0] | digest[1] << 8 | digest[2] << 16 | digest[3] << 24
print number # Out: 295970696
print socket.htonl(number) # Out: 2284299281
print struct.unpack('<i', digest[:4])[0] # Out: 295970696
```

I used [BitConverter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,e8230d40857425ba) source to understand the conversion.
If I modify the C# code to use a skip value of 0, then the C# output values match the python values.

```
 BitConverter.ToInt32(h.ComputeHash(chars), 0);
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: -2068185866 is 0x84b9fcf6, so basically you just take the last 8 digits from the md5digest, and convert that into an integer.

Comment: @Wimmel `struct.unpack('>i', m.hexdigest()[-8:].decode('hex'))[0]` That did the trick, thanks.

Comment: So, you want to convert a 128 but value to a 32 but value?